# How to log into Google Play Game Services using CURL? Have Client Server Game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

So we have a client server game we've developed, since our game has to speak back to the server for all sorts of things, stats and such, the server actually generates things like leaderboards.

So it would make sense for our server to communicate to Google Play Game Services to submit leaderboard data.

We're not quite sure how to do this?

For an android device we do have the AppID. This really seems more like Server to Server communication that we're wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a REST API for this kind of scenario. You'll authenticate using OAuth 2.0. Take a look at the [documentation specifically for client-server web](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/serverlogin).

Comment: Right but the issue is there is a Redirect URI with a web domain being requested as well as a JavaScript origins. We want to do this on behalf of Android users and in the future, our iOS and Web users. Our backend server is using PHP and when we try to connect we get the following error.  - { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API" } }

Answer (score 0):

We have a REST API which you can call from your server:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/index

You could get the access token from the device and transmit it securely to the server. Then the server can make the API calls via the REST API.

Comment: Hi Bruno, we tried to log in via curl with the client ID & secret (web client method) but got the following. { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "HTTP Basic Authentication is not supported for this API" } }  How do we have our server start making calls to the GPServer if we're doing this on behalf of an android user? We have the AppID from the Android device. Its the transmission part via php we're unsure of.